# How can I make my python code detect key presses on MacOs?

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm an absolute noob to python. I'm wondering if there's a way I can make Python detect key presses on my keyboard on macOS. I've tried using the keyboard module but to no success. Can anyone help and/or just guide me?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the keyboard [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L509) there are some ideas, if you want to continue using this library.

In particular, if you want to wait repeatedly on a key press, I would recommend the section in the documentation called: "Repeatedly waiting for a key press" which has the exact commands to run in order to achieve this. It also is very helpful because it gives you examples of what to do and what not to do when using the library.

For instance, I found the following basic example helpful:

```
import keyboard


keyboard.add_hotkey('space', lambda: print('space was pressed!'))

keyboard.wait('space')
```

After running this, the program will wait for your input. If you press space, the output:

```
space was pressed!
```

will be generated, and the program will terminate. Also, I needed to run the python file as an administrator (I put sudo in front of the command for this, not sure if this is recommended or secure).

I hope this helps guide you.

**Edit:**
Using sudo on the command line. I use VS code, so I just press the "up" arrow on my command line to go to the most recent command, and then I type sudo in front. See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: So I tried using this exact example in Python, but at the bottom of the errors, it says "OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator". Thing is, I have no idea how to be an administrator. You said "Also, I needed to run the python file as an administrator (I put sudo in front of the command for this, not sure if this is recommended or secure)." but where do you do this command with "sudo" to make yourself an administrator?

Comment: @TofuSalmon You just put sudo in front of the python command you’re running on the command line in your IDE or console. I'll add some pictures of my console to show you